# sendKeys(Keys.DOWN) is not moving to the option in the auto suggestive dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: Ocupation]I'm trying to select an option from an auto suggestive dropdown. When I enter the string into the dropdown sendKeys(keys.down) is not moving to the option. I'm getting a 'cannot focus element' error. 
I have added screen shots of the co[image: Aviva Code]de and the dropdown on the screen. This is the code.

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('proposer.occupation- selectized').value = 'Composer';");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[4](https://services.aviva.ie/direct/product/car.htm?_flowId=motor-flow&_flowExecutionKey=e1s1.)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIlVP.png)/div[8]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gA9g.png)/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIlVP.png)/div")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
        driver.findElement(By.id("proposer.occupation-selectized")).getText();
        String script = "return document.getElementById('proposer.occupation-selectized').value;";

```
    String text=(String) jse.executeScript(script);
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Comment: Please share (at least ) the code, and the full exception. Asking questions in the right format will increase your chances of a decent answer dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code to select the options from the autosuggestion drop down using keys.down

```
        WebElement Occupation_textbox = driver.findElement(By.id("proposer.occupation-selectized")); //To locate the occupation textbox
    Occupation_textbox.sendKeys("Develop"+Keys.DOWN+"\n"); //To enter the occupation search string and then go one down and select the option --or-- you can add a wait for the dropdown element to be visible and then take the current element and then go down (Keys.down)   "Occupation_textbox.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN+"\n")"; 

    WebElement Occupation_selected_text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='proposer.occupation-selectized']/preceding-sibling::div")); //Locate element to capture the text of the selected option

    //There are two ways you can take out the value on your page
    String value_way1 = Occupation_selected_text.getAttribute("data-value"); // to take the text from data-value attribute 
    String value_way2 = Occupation_selected_text.getText(); // to get the text in the search field

    System.out.println(value_way1);
    System.out.println(value_way2);
```

Comment: Hi Ravikar,                                                                                                    Thanks for your solution. This worked I can search an option in the drop down and select it. My Java experience is little and I'm learning with some online education.

Comment: Hello @Paul, I'm glad to hear that. Can you please mark my suggestion as the solution then.